# Will this 3v3 level shift for arduino->avr programmer work

Tags: arduino, voltage, spi, level-shifting, icsp

I'm trying to program an avr in a circuit that has other components on the same SPI lines that would be damaged with > 3.3 volt logic.

I figured I could just use an arduino (5v logic) with a level shifter I have laying around.

Does this circuit look like it could work? I wasn't sure how to deal with MISO.

I added leds on the MOSI and CS/Reset lines for added dazzle.

[image]

**Updated schematic**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

As a bare minimum your "dazzle" LEDs are going to require a series resistor to limit current through the LEDs. Even if the 'HC4050 can itself safely limit the LED current the LEDs as shown will clamp the swing of the signal voltage to the Vf drop of the LED. This will not be compatible with the target SPI device that you want to have 3.3V logic swings to.

Comment: did I get MISO right at least?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just butcher an Arduino to run on 3.3 V? It's simple enough to change the regulator on an Arduino. There are instructions [here](https://learn.adafruit.com/arduino-tips-tricks-and-techniques/3-3v-conversion) on Adafruit....step by step.

Comment: I'm surprised that they don't replace the 16MHz crystal with an 8MHz one in that tutorial.

Comment: @NickAlexeev. It's hardly worth it since you can run on the internal 8Mhz clock. The crystal only really provides benefits for very accurate Timers or very high baud rates, most of the time you really don't need an accurate clock. YMMV of course.

Comment: @JackCreasey well, for synchronous serial protocols like SPI, you need to have a reasonably stable clock. With the internal 8Mhz oscillator, you can have jitter and temperature deviations way out of spec for the SPI clock depending of course what frequency you are running it at. Would have to run it pretty darn slow to get it to work reliably.

Comment: @KyranF - you are extremely mistaken in your conclusion.  You don't really need a very stable clock for SPI at all, that is in effect the whole point of a *synchronous* interface.  Minimum times would be required at points in the waveform, but those are orders of magnitude beyond the result of plausible variation.

Comment: as it happens i only have one genuine and full-size arduino, and i'd rather not do something partially destructible to it. I have a bunch of level shifters though

Comment: also i don't have a 3.3v regulator of sufficient size